# Can anyone help with a java problem regarding date properties?

Tags: java, java-me

I basically want to say

if the date is unchanged run this alert

my date field is set up like this

```
                StartDate = new DateField("Start Date ", DateField.DATE);
                cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal1.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2009);
                cal1.set(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
                cal1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                StartDate.setDate(cal1.getTime());
```

and i have this but i am not sure where to begin to make it right.

```
        if(StartDate.equals(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1))
        {

        AlertNameNotEntered.setString("Please select a Start Date");
        mDisplay.setCurrent(AlertNameNotEntered);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: what exactly is what you want to do? Do you want to compare if a viven date is equals to the first day of month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
if(StartDate.getDate().getTime() == cal1.getTime()) // Date is unchanged
  {
    AlertNameNotEntered.setString("Please select a Start Date");
    mDisplay.setCurrent(AlertNameNotEntered);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you have quite a few gaps in your knowledge regarding basic Java. There are no short-cuts to getting to know the language and the standard library. Consult javadocs for [Calendar](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), [Date](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [DateField](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/DateField.html) classes.